# Java Socket dont receive all bytes

Tags: java, c#, sockets

I was playing around with the sockets and  encountered a problem.  I have a C# client continuesly sending bytes in such order:
byte[6] -> byte[30000] ->byte[6] -> byte[30000]; (without any break)

On java socket server im reading those bytes as follows:

```
byte[] mainBuffer = new byte[30000];
DataInputStream inputStream= new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
receivebytes=6;

   while(true){
         numberOfBytesRedFromStream  = inputStream.read(mainBuffer, 0, receiveBytes);
          ....
               if(receivebytes==6){
                   receibytes=30000;
                  }
               else{
                    receivebyter=6;
                    }
               }
```

but sometimes i simply dont receive full 30000 bytes its less .

Could you explain  why is it so ? 
I would really appreciate it. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple reasons that this could be happening, the client that is sending them might not be `flush()`ing and therefore not sending everything, or it could be because the amount of bytes you are sending is greater than your max frame size.

Take a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joncole/archive/2006/03/20/simple-message-framing-sample-for-tcp-socket.aspx) for more info

Comment: Server side:    while true{                              socketToServer.Send(numbers);
socketToServer.Send(data, 0, 30000, SocketFlags.None);}

Comment: i found out everything that i needed. Thank you for help :)